# iOS - Changing UIBarButtonItem's height

Tags: ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

UIToolbar has a nice option for resizing (self.navigationController.toolbar.frame) I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the height of a UIBarButtonItem?

I have a custom toolbar with a height of 117 pixels and so far I haven't found a way of modifying the buttons on the toolbar. Also I need it to be a toolbar because the displayed view gets covered with another animated view (cut scene style) while I setup assets in the first view and the toolbar needs to stay on top during all of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've actually run into this myself and the only thing I could come up with was leveraging initWithCustomView and passing in a UIButton with a defined frame.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

/*
* Insert button styling
*/

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Otherwise UIBarButtonItem only has a width property that can be set but unfortunately not a height property. Another nifty thing I've done with initWithCustomView is to pass in a toolbar with a button and other things like activity indicators. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

create a `UIButton` with your preferred frame and image and target and selector and etc. then use `UIBarButtonItem`'s `initWithCustomView:` method and use the UIButton as the customView.

Comment: You did post first but Octo's answer was more complete. I wish I could split the check mark. But I did find several of your posts insightful and gave them the upvote they deserved.

Answer (score 0):

Make this simple three steps

1 Write property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBarActive;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *uiButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *uiButtonItem;
```

2 Synthesize:

```
@synthesize toolBarActive = _toolBarActive;
@synthesize uiButton = _uiButton;
@synthesize uiButtonItem = _uiButtonItem;
```

3 Write implementation:

```
-(UIToolbar *) toolBarActive {
    if( _toolBarActive == nil ) {
        _toolBarActive = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 40)];
        _toolBarActive.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];  
        NSMutableArray *arrayItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arrayItem addObject:self.uiButtonItem];
        [_toolBarActive setItems:arrayItem animated:YES];
    }
    return _toolBarActive;
}

- (UIButton *) uiButton {
    if( _uiButton == nil ) {
        _uiButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
        [_uiButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePointFromTrip) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_uiButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"editable.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return _uiButton;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *) uiButtonItem {
    if( _uiButtonItem == nil ) {
        _uiButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.uiButton];
        [_uiButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
    }
    return _uiButtonItem;
}
```

Now when you have uibutton on uibarbuttomitem you can define all property for uibutton like, image, action etc.